# Angular subscribe: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Tags: angular

Сервис отдает данные в подписку в неверном формате, помогите привести к нужному виду.

**Сервис**

```
getStats() {

            let statsLS = localStorage.getItem('stats');
            let slt = +localStorage.getItem('slt');

            let date = new Date();
            let time = date.getTime();

            if(statsLS === null || slt < time) {
                this.http.get('/server/api/statsService').subscribe((data: any) => {
                    this.stats = data;
                            let date = new Date();
                            let time = date.getTime()+60000+'';
                            localStorage.setItem('stats',JSON.stringify(this.stats));
                            localStorage.setItem('slt',time);
                            return this.stats;  
                    });
                } else {
                    return JSON.parse(statsLS);
                    }

        }

}
```

**Компонент**

```
ngOnInit() { 
this.statsService.getStats().subscribe((data: any) => console.log(data));
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Comment: Помогли тут https://qna.habr.com/q/744631 Не знаю как пометить как решенный